# Функция для прохождения по списку списков и поиска аналогов

Tags: python

Есть список, содержащий некоторое количество элементов - списков.

Списки внутри состоят из двух элементов – целых чисел, которые обозначают id товаров

- (например, `[[1102, 214], [214, 2007], [42, 315], [406, 2007], …]`).

Каждая пара внутри – пара аналогов товаров. Считаем, что если товар 1 и товар 2 - аналоги (1102 и 214), товар 2 и товар 3 – аналоги (214, 2007), то и товар 1 является аналогом товара 3 (1102 аналог 2007), даже если этой пары нет в исходном списке. Товар 1, товар 2 и товар 3 назовем группой аналогов. Необходимо написать функцию на Python, которая на вход принимает список списков и выводит
на экран наиболее полные группы аналогов в виде кортежей (комментарии к коду
приветствуются).

Пример:
имеется список:

```
lst = [[1102, 214], [214, 2007], [42, 315], [406, 2007], [100, 200], [315, 77]]
```

Ожидаемый вывод:

```
1102, 214, 2007, 406
42, 315, 77
100, 200
```

Пробовал пройти по списку циклом, но не очень понимаю как обращаться отдельно к индексам внутри списка, как логично построить условие.
Буду рад любому дельному совету.

Comment: Интересная задачка. Так то в лоб можно пройтись и составить множества, но потом их ещё как-то объединять нужно будет.

Comment: есть решение с помощью networkx, то есть, через графы (что правильно). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842613/merge-lists-that-share-common-elements

Comment: @strawdog Да, тут явно граф напрашивается, "вручную" это всё обходить и объединять как-то муторно выглядит.

Comment: @strawdog спасибо. Одно из решений по ссылке помогло. Суть алгоритма понятна (его приводит автор). Но некоторые моменты кода пока непонятны. Попробую разобраться, так как хочется именно понимать решение. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ссылку. Завернул одно из решений в функцию:

```
def analog(l):
      
    out = []
    while len(l)>0:
        first, *rest = l
        first = set(first)
    
        lf = -1
        while len(first)>lf:
            lf = len(first)
    
            rest2 = []
            for r in rest:
                if len(first.intersection(set(r)))>0:
                    first |= set(r)
                else:
                    rest2.append(r)     
            rest = rest2
    
        out.append(first)
        l = rest
    
    # print(out)
    print('\n'.join(map(str, out)))
```

Вывод:

```
{214, 2007, 406, 1102}
{42, 315, 77}
{200, 100}
None
```